# Nginx location try_files match everything but root

Tags: nginx

I have a location block that looks something like:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files /legacy$uri /legacy$uri/ $bootstrap?$args;
}
```

This works create except when I go to http://localhost/ it matches to `/legacy/` which isn't what I want. How can I try_files except for when `$uri` is simply a slash?

Answer (score 4):

Add another location block:

```
location  = / {
  //do something
}
```

As per the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location), nginx will:

1. Only match one location block
2. Will choose the location block based on the following:

   1. Matches using "="
   2. Conventional strings using "^~"
   3. Regular expressions (in the order listed)
   4. All other conventional strings

Therefore, requests for the top level (/) will match the location block above, while all other requests will match your existing location block.